# Second TouchBar

Tags: swift4.2, nstouchbar, nsstoryboard

I have two sroryboards in my macOS app (with two separated WindowControllers). I'm wondering how I could in XCode IDE create two TouchBars each connected to own Window Controller Scene in storyboard. Actually I can create two TouchBars but just the one from Main storyboard is shown when I run the app.
What's proper way to customize TouchBar for the second storyboard window?
Thanks.

Comment: You can keep your main touchbar but add `.otherItemsProxy` in it and then add only the additional parts in the children touchbar (so that they insert themselves into the main one).

Comment: It helped finally, thanks.